# Encoding Url In C With Line Breaks?

Tags: c, url-encoding

I've got this url encoder I found on the internet and made few small changes, however when ever I do something such as this:

```
char encodedWord[100];
const char* word = "Stack\nOverflow";

urlencode(encodedWord, word);
```

The output would be something like this:
"Stack0X8.51EE00001674P-1022Overflow" instead of x0A in between of Stack Overflow.

Why is it outputting that? I assume because of the "*EE0000*" part something went wrong with the char to number conversion.

How can I get my encoder to be much more friendly to special characters? i.e "\n,\r,\r".

### The Function

```
int urlencode(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    /* urlencode all non-alphanumeric characters in the C-string 'src'
       store result in the C-string 'dest'
       return the length of the url encoded C-string
    */
    char *d;
    int i;
    for(i=0, d=dest; src[i]; i++) {
        if(isalnum(src[i]) || isdigit(src[i])) {
            *(d++) = src[i];
        } else {
            snprintf(d, 4, "%%%02X", src[i]);
            d += 3;
        }
    }   
    *d = 0;
    return d-dest;
}
```

### System

Windows 10 32bit
Mingw32 (gcc 5.1.0)

### Make File

```
#OBJS specifies which files to compile as part of the project

OBJS = $(wildcard ./src/*.c)

#CC specifies which compiler we're using
CC = gcc

#INCLUDE_PATHS specifies the additional include paths we'll need
INCLUDE_PATHS = 

#LIBRARY_PATHS specifies the additional library paths we'll need
LIBRARY_PATHS = 

#COMPILER_FLAGS specifies the additional compilation options we're using
# -w suppresses all warnings
# -Wl,-subsystem,windows gets rid of the console window
COMPILER_FLAGS = -Wall -Wl,-subsystem,console -std=c99

#LINKER_FLAGS specifies the libraries we're linking against
LINKER_FLAGS = -lmingw32 -lws2_32 -lwininet -s -lshlwapi

#OBJ_NAME specifies the name of our executable
OBJ_NAME = project

#This is the target that compiles our executable
all : clean build

build:
    cls
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OBJ_NAME)

clean:
    del -f $(OBJ_NAME).exe
```

Comment: I get `Stack%0AOverflow` as expected. GCC 5.4, Linux.

Comment: Perhaps it's a environment setting in my make file? I'll post it too in just a sec.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What you have given is almost there so you just need to edit it a little to show *exactly* the code that you are running to produce that output, including how you are printing it.

Comment: The behavior of `snprintf()` in ISO is different than MS. Check this [out](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/31241434/).

Comment: Ah forgot to show what I'm printing with. Work with so many languages. Starting to forget the finer details in C especially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `urlencode` function is working just fine, the problem is how you're printing the output. I was in the middle of writing

> `0X8.51EE00001674P-1022` is a hexadecimal floating point number, what you would expect to see from a `%A` printf specifier.

when it struck me that the correct output has `%0A` in that exact position. Which means that you're making the mistake of passing a non-constant string as the first parameter of `printf`. Don't do `printf(encodedWord)`; you should be using `printf("%s", encodedWord)` instead.

Comment: Awesome, couldn't have asked for a better answer.